# ASP.NET Repeater - show part of data in column and full data in a tool tip

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET project I want to show the first 20 characters (only a part of the full text) and then display the full text in a tool tip. I need to do because the description can be up to 500 characters long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a label control in the repeater, you can do something like this to shorten the tooltip.

```
 <asp:Label   
      ID="Label1"
      Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("description")).Substring(0, 20) %>'
      ToolTip='<%# Eval("description") %>'
      runat="server"  />
```

Comment: It should be the other way around, ToolTip = '<%# Eval("description") %>' (full text), and Text='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("description")).Substring(0, 20) %>'

Comment: @Bokka: so it should! @Bala R: I took the liberty of correcting it for you, feel free to put it back if you want ;)

Comment: Is it necessary to use `Convert.ToString()`? Could you not just use `Eval("description").ToString().Substring(0, 20)`?

Comment: @Town thanks for the edit. I misread that part of the question. @James `Convert.ToString()` handles null well whereas `Eval().ToString()` would cause NRE.

Comment: Possible problem: this would only work if the 'description' property was guaranteed to be at least 20 characters

Answer (score 1):

Hey I just blogged about how to do that in detail [HERE.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2010/07/06/Displaying-a-Long-Description-Column-in-a-GridView.aspx)  This uses the GridView.

It ends up looking like this:

[image]